# custom zsh autocomplete

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

I'd like to write a zsh completion for pytest.

Where do I Start? I'm using oh-my-zsh.

in .zshrc:

```
fpath=($HOME/.mycompletions $fpath)
autoload -U compinit && compinit -u
```

in $HOME/.mycompletions/_pytest:

```
#compdef pytest

_pytest()
{
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    COMPREPLY=(`pytestcomplete ${cur} 2>/dev/null`)
}
complete -o nospace -F _pytest py.test
```

Is this correct so far?

Now I "only" need to write the `pytestcomplete` script.

What should the Return values Look like? How can I hand over to the script which parts have been completed?

I.e. if a user does `py.test<TAB>` it should complete files first.
If one does `py.test tests/my.test.py<TAB>` it should complete class names.
If one does `py.test tests/my.test.py::TestClass<TAB>` it should complete method names.

To get the info out of pytest, one would use `--collect-only`. The only problem at the moment is the back and forth between zsh and the completion script.

And can this be done like this or do I need to write a oh-my-zsh plugin?

Comment: The usage of `COMPREPLY` looks more like bashcompletion than zsh completion, although [zsh can use bash completions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249432/i-have-a-bash-tab-completion-script-is-there-a-simple-way-to-use-it-from-zsh). Did you check the howtos for [zsh](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions/blob/master/zsh-completions-howto.org) and [bash](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.ch/2011/04/writing-your-own-bash-completion.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write your own completion function for that. You can simply re-use `pytest`'s Bash completion:

1. Install `argcomplete`:

   ```bsh
   pip install argcomplete
   ```
2. Add the following to your `.zshrc`:

   ```bsh
   autoload -Uz bashcompinit && bashcompinit
   eval "$(register-python-argcomplete pytest)"
   ```
3. Restart your shell.
4. Done!